# How to design system to support read/write at the same time like google doc?

Tags: architecture, system-design

This is a system design question asked in a google interview. Interviewer wants to design a system to support google doc. It allows multiple persons to edit the doc at same time and have good experience of editing it on local machine.

Comment: what do you mean specific question?

Answer (score 2):

I think this question is valid and meaningful. I was asked the question too.
How to design a google doc to support concurrent editing?

Apparently, using lock for each read/write will bring poor performance and terrible end user experience.

It is something called Differential Synchronization.
https://neil.fraser.name/writing/sync/